# Can't use having sum or having count mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a table like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=14f54944ec1fdb39569126bec0be397b)

```
CREATE TABLE order_match(ID int(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
quantity decimal(10,2), createdAt date NOT NULL, order_status_id int(10) NOT NULL,
createdby int(11), code_order varchar(20) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE air_way_bills (id int(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
code_order varchar(30) NOT NULL, customer_regency varchar(30) NOT NULL);

insert into air_way_bills values
(1, 0001, 'KOTA DEPOK'),
(2, 0002, 'KOTA JAKARTA'),
(3, 0003, 'KOTA BOGOR'),
(4, 0004, 'KOTA BOGOR'),
(5, 0005, 'KOTA TANGERANG'),
(6, 0006, 'KOTA JAMBI'),
(7, 0007, 'KOTA BOGOR'),
(8, 0009, 'KOTA TANGERANG');

insert into order_match values
(1, 0.2, '2020-02-02', 6, 01, 0001),
(2, 1, '2020-02-03', 7, 02, 0002),
(3, 1.3, '2020-02-04', 7, 03, 0003),
(4, 1.4, '2020-02-08', 5, 08, 0004),
(5, 1.2, '2020-02-05', 8, 04, 0005),
(6, 1.4, '2020-03-01', 8, 05, 0006),
(7, 0.23, '2020-01-01', 8, 03, 0007),
(8, 2.3, '2020-02-07', 8, 04, 0009);
```

this is table order_match, the id with the primary key, quantity is the quantity of the transaction, createdAt are the date transaction, order_status_id is the status of the transaction (with order_status_id 7 are not approved transaction), createdby are the users, and code_order are the destination and connected with air_way_bills code_order column

```
+----+----------+------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+
| ID | quantity | createdAt  | order_status_id | createdby | code_order |
+----+----------+------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+
|  1 |     0.20 | 2020-02-02 |               6 |         1 |          1 |
|  2 |     1.00 | 2020-02-03 |               7 |         2 |          2 |
|  3 |     1.30 | 2020-02-04 |               7 |         3 |          3 |
|  4 |     1.40 | 2020-02-08 |               5 |         8 |          4 |
|  5 |     1.20 | 2020-02-05 |               8 |         4 |          5 |
|  6 |     1.40 | 2020-03-01 |               8 |         5 |          6 |
|  7 |     0.23 | 2020-01-01 |               8 |         3 |          7 |
|  8 |     2.30 | 2020-02-07 |               8 |         4 |          9 |
+----+----------+------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+
```

this is air_way_bills table, `with order_match.code_order = air_way_bills.code_order`

```
+----+------------+------------------+
| id | code_order | customer_regency |
+----+------------+------------------+
|  1 |          1 | KOTA DEPOK       |
|  2 |          2 | KOTA JAKARTA     |
|  3 |          3 | KOTA BOGOR       |
|  4 |          4 | KOTA BOGOR       |
|  5 |          5 | KOTA TANGERANG   |
|  6 |          6 | KOTA JAMBI       |
|  7 |          7 | KOTA BOGOR       |
|  8 |          9 | KOTA TANGERANG   |
+----+------------+------------------+
```

i want to find out the new users (createdby) in range date '2020-02-03' until '2020-02-07' with approval transaction (order_status_id not in 7) and sort with in the destination. new users is the users where doing transaction in between the range date, but never doing transaction before the date range (on this case, before '2020-02-03')

i used this query

```
SELECT COALESCE(customer_regency, 'Total') AS `Destination`, 
       SUM(quantity) AS `Qty(kg)`,
       round(SUM(quantity) / any_value(totalsum) * 100, 1) AS `Qty(%)`, 
       COUNT(a.id) AS `Jumlah Order`,
       round(COUNT(a.id) / any_value(totalcount) * 100, 1) AS `Jumlah Order(%)`
FROM order_match a

/* 1 */ INNER JOIN air_way_bills b
/* 1 */ ON a.code_order = b.code_order
/* 2 */ INNER JOIN ( SELECT s1.createdby
               FROM order_match s1
               WHERE s1.order_status_Id in (4, 5, 6, 8)
               GROUP BY s1.createdby
               HAVING COUNT(s1.createdAt BETWEEN '2020-02-03' AND '2020-02-07') >= 1)
                  AND COUNT(s1.createdAt < '2020-02-03') = 0 ) clients 
/* 2 */ ON a.createdby = clients.createdby
JOIN ( SELECT SUM(quantity) totalsum, 
              COUNT(id) totalcount 
       FROM order_match
/* 3 */  INNER JOIN ( SELECT s2.createdby
                      FROM order_match s2
                      WHERE s2.order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8)
                      GROUP BY s2.createdby
                      HAVING COUNT(s2.createdAt BETWEEN '2020-02-03' AND '2020-02-07') >= 1)
                         AND COUNT(s2.createdAt < '2020-02-03') = 0 ) clients
/* 3 */ ON order_match.createdby = clients.createdby
       WHERE order_status_Id in (4, 5, 6, 8)) totals
WHERE a.order_status_Id in (4, 5, 6, 8)
GROUP BY customer_regency WITH ROLLUP;
```

but it says

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND COUNT(s1.createdAt < '2020-02-03') = 0 ) clients 
/* 2 */ ON a.createdby = c' at line 15
```

expected results

```
+----------------+---------+--------+--------------+-----------------+
| Destination    | Qty(kg) | Qty(%) | Count Order  | Count Order(%) |
+----------------+---------+--------+--------------+-----------------+
| KOTA TANGERANG |    3.50 |    100 |            2 |             100 |
| Total          |    3.50 |  100.0 |            2 |           100.0 |
+----------------+---------+--------+--------------+-----------------+
```

explanation : because users (Createdby) 4 are only fit with the condition (doing transaction in range date and never doing transaction before, and had approval transaction (order_status_id not in 7)

Comment: guess, you have an extra closing brace after >= 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(customer_regency, 'Total') AS `Destination`,
       SUM(quantity) AS `Qty(kg)`,
       round(SUM(quantity) / any_value(totalsum) * 100, 1) AS `Qty(%)`,
       COUNT(a.id) AS `Jumlah Order`,
       round(COUNT(a.id) / any_value(totalcount) * 100, 1) AS `Jumlah Order(%)`
FROM order_match a

/* 1 */ INNER JOIN air_way_bills b
/* 1 */ ON a.code_order = b.code_order
/* 2 */ INNER JOIN ( SELECT s1.createdby
               FROM order_match s1
               WHERE s1.order_status_Id in (4, 5, 6, 8)
               GROUP BY s1.createdby
               HAVING (SUM(case when createdAt >= '2020-02-03' AND createdAt <= '2020-02-07' then 1 else 0 end) >= 1)
                  AND SUM(case when createdAt < '2020-02-03' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 ) clients
/* 2 */ ON a.createdby = clients.createdby
JOIN ( SELECT SUM(quantity) totalsum,
              COUNT(id) totalcount
       FROM order_match
/* 3 */  INNER JOIN ( SELECT s2.createdby
                      FROM order_match s2
                      WHERE s2.order_status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8)
                      GROUP BY s2.createdby
                      HAVING SUM(case when createdAt >= '2020-02-03' AND createdAt <= '2020-02-07' then 1 else 0 end) >= 1
                         AND SUM(case when createdAt < '2020-02-03' then 1 else 0 end) = 0  ) clients
/* 3 */ ON order_match.createdby = clients.createdby
       WHERE order_status_Id in (4, 5, 6, 8)) totals
WHERE a.order_status_Id in (4, 5, 6, 8)
GROUP BY customer_regency WITH ROLLUP;
```

1. remove redundant `)` after `COUNT(s1.createdAt BETWEEN '2020-02-03' AND '2020-02-07') >= 1)`
2. change `count` to `sum`. their differences please refer to office doc

> The COUNT(expression) returns the number of rows that do not contain
> NULL values as the result of the expression.
>
> The SUM() function is an aggregate function that allows you to
> calculate the sum of values in a set. The syntax of the SUM() function
> is as follows: